# Rails: 'Could not find table' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I developped a simple rails application that runs perfectly on my development machine.

When I put it on the production server (Phusion Passenger/Nginx), it returns me that error in the `my_app/log/production.log` file:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'categories')
```

What is wrong?

PS: After a naming error, the table name was edited manually but it works great in the development mode. I don't suspect that misnaming error.

Comment: have you run `rake db:migrate` on your server yet?

Comment: Indeed. I forgot to execute the following command: `rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"`. Please, post your comment so that I can mark it as the best answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Make sure you've run your database migrations on the production server
2. Manually editing tables is a huge **no no** in Rails. It'll give you more headaches than it is worth. If you need to change something, you're way better of generating a new migration to change it - even if it's just a name change. (You can however rollback the db changes, delete that last migration and create a new one - but like I said - it's more trouble than it's worth)
3. Make sure your schema xml file is correct or at least matching to the actual schema. You can delete this and run rake:db:migrate to generate a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You can manully assign table name for ActiveRecord Models to prevent these misnaming Errors.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'categories'
end
```

Comment: Live long and prosper for this advice! You helped me a lot!